# How to simulate monochrome / greyscale camera in Gazebo?

Tags: gazebo-11, gazebo-camera

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Is there a proper way to simulate monochrome / greyscale camera in Gazebo?

The [answer to question #3470](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/3470/quick-question-what-is-color-descption-and-format-in-sdf/) suggests setting the `<format>` tag to `L8`. This almost works as expected, but I noticed that the output image *only uses the red channel of the rendered scene*. Thus a blue object would appear as black, as shown below:

[image: image description]

Is there a way to get the sensor to output the mean greyscale value (e.g. `(R+G+B)/3`)?

Edit: adding a photo showing the same result in RViz and the Gazebo Topic Visualizer, as well as showing the ambient and background color settings
[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/27793/how-to-simulate-monochrome-/-greyscale-camera-in-gazebo?/) by [shonigmann](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/47307/shonigmann/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 16 on 2022-02-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Looking at the source code, it looks [like L8 and L_INT8 set `bpp` to 8](https://github.com/osrf/gazebo/blob/cc06796b135f03066a96c68dfa4e2f89d5f76b3a/gazebo/common/Image.cc#L131-L133), which is used by [`FreeImage_ConvertFromRawBits()`](https://github.com/osrf/gazebo/blob/gazebo11/gazebo/common/Image.cc#L166-L167) as [the bit-depth](https://documentation.help/FreeImage.NET/M_FreeImageAPI_FreeImage_ConvertFromRawBits.htm):

> bpp
> Type: SystemUInt32
> The bit depth (bits per pixel) of the raw bitmap.

I have a hunch that the renderer is producing an RGB image by default, and the `L8` option is just taking the first 8 bits of each pixel, i.e. the Red channel only.

Certainly more efficient than averaging over the 3 channels for each frame, but it feels a bit misleading... I'll open an [issue on the Gazebo github](https://github.com/osrf/gazebo/issues/3168), but given the massive issue backlog I have doubts anything will come of it. For my purposes I will likely end up writing a plugin to average RGB images into grey scale.

---

Originally posted by [shonigmann](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/47307/shonigmann/) with karma: 16 on 2022-02-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Veerachart](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/39778/veerachart/) on 2022-02-08**:
There is an example for [B&W OGRE compositor](https://wiki.ogre3d.org/Compositor#Black_REAL_AMP_White). Add the compositor to the OGRE camera of an RGB camera sensor (via sensor plugin), and more correct grey RGB images can be obtained. Necessary files can be found from [these files](https://github.com/OGRECave/ogre/tree/v1-9-0/Samples/Media/materials). GLSL 150 should be good for Gazebo on Ubuntu.
Would be better to get output in 1 channel anyway.

**Comment by [shonigmann](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/47307/shonigmann/) on 2022-02-08**:
Interesting - thanks for the resources! We may go this route if we end up needing "true" mono. for now, we're going to see how much mileage we can get out of `L8`

**Comment by [Veerachart](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/39778/veerachart/) on 2022-02-08**:
There is actually a [sample browser from OGRE](https://snapcraft.io/ogre) that you can install and see the samples (the version will be quite newer than what Gazebo is using). They look quite different from what we see from Gazebo. I've been trying to pick out some tricks to improve model's look in the cameras, not actually successful though.